# Can't make a good way to find number of active touch points on the document using a function

Tags: javascript, function, touch-event

I'm trying to get this function to show the number of touchpoints on the screen, but I need it to be instant and accurate. This code works, but when I touch the screen fast it sometimes resolves the "num" variable as 1 when it should be 0. I tried adding a debounce but it still didn't really fix it. I am new to this so any help is appreciated.

```
async number() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let num = 0;
    let timeoutId = null;

    const updateNum = (e) => {
      num = e.touches.length;
      if (timeoutId) {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      }
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(num);
        timeoutId = null;
      }, 50);
    };

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', updateNum);
    document.addEventListener('touchend', updateNum);
  });
}
```

I tried it without the debounce with this code:

```
async number() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let num = 0;
    const updateNum = (e) => {
      num = e.touches.length;
      resolve(num);
    };
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', updateNum);
    document.addEventListener('touchend', updateNum);
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', updateNum);
  });
}
```

But the issue I ran into is that the resolved variable wasn't accurate when two touch points were added at the exact same time.